# Have a main table auto-update sub-tables on separate worksheets (Excel 2010)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I have been trying to figure this out for a while and although I've found partial answers here and there, I haven't found a complete solution.

Here are the facts:

- I'm using Excel 2010 and can't install add-ons or extensions.
- Worksheet "All Audits" - This has data relating to all active audits and is our master list.

  - There is data in columns A:L
  - There is a header in row 1 and data in the rows below
  - Column D and E contain primary and secondary audit leads
  - Manual updates will occur on this sheet
  - All other worksheets have the same headings and structure
- Worksheet "Department1"

  - This page will list all audits belonging to Department 1 (whether as primary or secondary)
- Worksheet "Department2"

  - This page will list all audits belonging to Department 2 (whether as primary or secondary)

Essentially I want to make it so as audits are updated manually in the main list, Excel will automatically copy/paste the row to the next blank row in the appropriate Department sheet depending on which owner/department is identified in column D and E.

Any help would be tremendously appreciated!

Comment: Have you considered using a PivotTable instead? There is an approach for this in VBA, but it will be terribly inefficient and it will also be error prone (not to mention that if record 'A' is removed from the `master`, your current approach wouldn't remove it from the corresponding sheet).

Comment: Could pivot tables pull the appropriate row depending on the owner value? and can the resulting pivot table be formatted to look a certain way? In the end I'd like it to be as brainless as possible and essentially have people only update the master list and have that show in the individual ownership worksheets.

Answer (score 0):

PivotTables would be the best option for this task. They allow you to quickly summarize your data using labels or categories, and allow for slicers that can make the data even easier to consume.

There are numerous ways to design the PivotTable, but it will be up to you to decide what works best for your aesthetic. My recommendation would be to start with formatting your master as a Table (if it isnt already) and then naming it (All_Audits_Master would be a good name). Then in your master list add a column that calculates your two groups. So for example, the formula would look something like:

`=If(OR([Primary Department]="Department1", [Secondary Department]="Department1"), "Department1", If(Or([Primary Department]="Department2", [Secondary Department]="Department2"), "Department2", "")`

This formula may look complicated at first, but all it does is uses the column names `[Some Name]` to check for a value, and labels the calculated column appropriately. If the record doesn't belong to either department, it returns a blank string.

Once you have that column (be sure to put it at the end so it doesn't interfere with pasting in your data) you just need two pivot tables. The first will use a filter for `Department1`, the second for `Department2`.

From there, I would put each of your columns that you want in your report within the `Rows` field. You can also use values if you want to summarize anything. For example, you could put a `Count` of `RecordID` into `Values` to count the number of records by department.

Ultimately there will be some up-front time cost of learning PivotTables but I assure you that if you can't use PivotTables yet, you will not want to mess with VBA. I spent literal months learning things in VBA that a PivotTable could have done for me in minutes. Additionally, once you do learn Pivot's more thoroughly, a lot more concepts will make sense (and will be available to you) in VBA.

Check out this tutorial to get started if you are a more visual learner: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=peNTp5fuKFg.

EDIT: The only thing to note is that the pivot table won't auto update. You have two options there:

Have users refresh the pivot after updating the master (Data > Refresh or Refresh All), or write a macro that handles that (using events, but this is not recommended unless as a last resort).